# FragmentTransaction commit multiple tasks is not work

Tags: android

I have two fragments in my activity. When I switch fragment use the code:

```
private void switchCourseFragment() {
    if (mCourseFragment == null || getActivity().isFinishing()) return;
    FragmentTransaction mTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if (mFragmentLogin != null && mFragmentLogin.isAdded()) {
        mTransaction.remove(mFragmentLogin);
    }
    if (!mCourseFragment.isAdded()) {
        mTransaction.add(R.id.learncenter_contain, mCourseFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

But this is not what I expected. The `mFragmentLogin` is not been removed, but the `mCourseFragment` is been added.

Comment: You're not commiting your remove transaction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to commit for it to take effect.

```
private void switchCourseFragment() {
    if (mCourseFragment == null || getActivity().isFinishing()) return;
    if (mFragmentLogin != null && mFragmentLogin.isAdded()) {
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(mFragmentLogin).commit();
    }
    if (!mCourseFragment.isAdded()) {
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.learncenter_contain, mCourseFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

but why don't you use `replace` instead?

```
private void switchCourseFragment() {
    if (mCourseFragment == null || getActivity().isFinishing()) return;
    if (!mCourseFragment.isAdded()) {
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.learncenter_contain, mCourseFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

This assume that both your fragments are in the same container.

Comment: Thanks! My understanding is that FragmentTransaction can perform multiple tasks,at last commits all tasks.May be I had it wrong!

Comment: @user6703435 It *CAN* perform multiple tasks but it is a fluent interface. So you have to use the return value of `mTransaction.remove()`. For example, `mTransaction = mTransaction.remove(mFragmentLogin);`.